# メタサイトのロゴに「メタ」と書いてほしい

Tags: 機能の要求, デザイン, メタ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

カタカナ表記の方にも「メタ」と書いてあったほうがわかりやすいかと思うのですが、どうでしょうか。

現在でもMETAとは書かれていますが、よく似たパーツがメインサイトのロゴにもあるので、かえって紛らわしくなっているように思います。

Comment: ふとタイトルについても疑問に思ったので、そのあたりの議論を貼っておきます：[当サイトのタイトル](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/13/8000) [ブランド展開戦略: 「日本語版」と言わない](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1433/8000) [「メタ」という言葉が解りづらい](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1862/8000)

Answer (score 2):

賛成です。
「日本語でOK」の精神で訳してしまってもよいかもしれませんね。
[image: META logo proposal]